# Dynamically Created Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have some `<inputs>` that are dynamically created, and when `checked` they create a dynamic `array`, which gets stuffed into an `.ajax` post. All of it works with the exception of the dynamically created `array`.  If I manually create the `array` it works fine, I'm just having trouble creating it dynamically. The numbers used in the ID (infoID1, infoID2, infoID3) and Values (1,2,3) are created via a PHP loop (`infoID{$x}`).

Sample inputs

```
<input id="infoID1" type="checkbox" value=1/>
<input id="info1" type="text" value="something good"/>

<input id="infoID2" type="checkbox" value=2/>
<input id="info2" type="text" value="something bad" />

<input id="infoID3" type="checkbox" value=3/>
<input id="info3" type="text" value="something ugly" />
```

The below `dataArray` is where I'm having all kinds of problems.  I need to put both the ID and Value of the checked boxes in this dynamically created `dataArray` (using some type of loop) and add sequential numeric values to both the ID variable (`infoID + 1` becomes `infoID1`) and the values (`1,2,3`)

so it will end up looking like this...

```
var dataArray = {
    infoID1 : 1,
    info1 : "something good",
    infoID2 : 2,
    info2 : "something bad",
    infoID3 : 3,
    info3 : "something ugly"
};
```

The `dataArray` then gets stuffed into the `.ajax` post below.  The `.ajax` section is working fine.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "workingPage.php",
    data: dataArray,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (otherData) {
        $(doStuff);
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some changes to do :

1- Add name to your inputs like this :

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input id="infoID1" name="mycheckboxid[]" type="checkbox" value=1/>
<input id="info1" name="mycheckboxvalue[]" type="text" value="something good"/>

<input id="infoID2" name="mycheckboxid[]" type="checkbox" value=2/>
<input id="info2" name="mycheckboxvalue[]" type="text" value="something bad" />

<input id="infoID3" name="mycheckboxid[]" type="checkbox" value=3/>
<input id="info3" name="mycheckboxvalue[]" type="text" value="something ugly" />
</form>
```

2- Use serialize() function :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "workingPage.php",
    data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (otherData) {
        $(doStuff);
    }
});
```

That's it.

Comment: I tried a methond of `.serialize` before and I couldn't get it to work, but I also don't have the `inputs` in a `form`. I tried so many different methods that I have them all confused now. I'll give it a shot and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: If you can't change your code for some reasons, you can use $.each loop on your inputs and create your array. even knowing this not the best way, the way you do it, but here is the code : $(document).ready(function(){
    var inputs = $('input'),
        dataArray = {};
    
    $.each(inputs, function(index, input){
        dataArray[$(input).attr('id')] = $(input).val();
    });
    
    // your ajax query here
});

Comment: I remember why `.serialize` didn't work for me. I have other data that I can't get from `.serialize` (div's and spans), but stuffing the data into the array and posting it via `.ajax` did work. However, your 2nd suggestion of using `.each` will work very well for what I need. Thanks for both suggestions.